# Asking user how many values to update and update that many values in dictionary by using values from another list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Given one dictionary `dictionary` and a list `letter_frequency`:

```
letter_frequency=["e", "t", "a", "o", "i", "n", "s", "r", "h", "l", "d", "c", "u", "m", "f", "p", "g", "w", "y", "b", "v", "k", "x", "j", "q","z"]
dictionary={'s': 28, 'o': 24, 'c': 20, 'w': 20, 'g': 17, 'm': 17, 't': 17, 'k': 14, 'e': 11, 'n': 10, 'f': 8, 'd': 7, 'y': 7, 'i': 6, 'l': 6, 'q': 6, 'j': 5, 'a': 2, 'r': 2, 'u': 2, 'v': 2, 'z': 1, 'b': 0, 'h': 0, 'p': 0, 'x': 0}
```

Ask user to enter how  many values we have update? Like this:

`enter how  many values we have update?`

If the use enters 5, first 5 values in the dictionay will be replace with the corresponding values in the list letter_frequency i.e. key-value pair for first 5 changes to
`'s':'e', 'o':'t','c': 'a', 'w': 'o', 'g': 'i'` and rest all key-value pair remains same.
So the ouput should be:

```
{'s': 'e', 'o': 't', 'c': 'a', 'w': 'o', 'g': 'i', 'm': 'm', 't': 't', 'k': 'k', 'e': 'e', 'n': 'n', 'f': 'f', 'd': 'd', 'y': 'y', 'i': 'i', 'l': 'l', 'q': 'q', 'j': 'j', 'a': 'a', 'r': 'r', 'u': 'u', 'v': 'v', 'z': 'z', 'b': 'b', 'h': 'h', 'p': 'p', 'x': 'x'}
```

Comment: IN dictonary we have to replace only 5 values by useing list values

Comment: after that  we have to replace remaing dictionary values  by useing keys in dictonary

Comment: Are you sure the question text is correct?  The code reads like what you have for `dictinoary` is a frequency table, and vice-versa.

Comment: yes this text is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the `dictionary` items with `letter_frequency` and then enumerate its output so that you can use the indices to determine if you want to output the updated values or not in a dict comprehension:

```
n = int(input('Enter how many values to update: '))
print({k: l if i < n else k for i, ((k, _), l) in enumerate(zip(dictionary.items(), letter_frequency))})
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter how many values to update: 3
{'s': 'e', 'o': 't', 'c': 'a', 'w': 'w', 'g': 'g', 'm': 'm', 't': 't', 'k': 'k', 'e': 'e', 'n': 'n', 'f': 'f', 'd': 'd', 'y': 'y', 'i': 'i', 'l': 'l', 'q': 'q', 'j': 'j', 'a': 'a', 'r': 'r', 'u': 'u', 'v': 'v', 'z': 'z', 'b': 'b', 'h': 'h', 'p': 'p', 'x': 'x'}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do mark the answer that you find to best solve your problem by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

```
num= int(input("Enter how many values to update:" ))
for i,key in enumerate (dictionary.keys()):
    if i < num:
        dictionary[key] = letter_frequency[i]
    else:
        dictionary[key] = key
```

Check and let me know if it doesn't suit your need.

Comment: From the OP's expected output it's apparent that the OP also wants the dictionary values updated to be equal to the keys when `i >= num`.

Comment: @blhsing Thank you. I debugged the answer.